# C++ Implement subclasses that extends subInterfaces without overriding already overriden methods

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class

I created Interfaces (abstract classes) that expends other Interfaces in C++ and I tried to implement them but errors occur when I compile.

**Here are the errors:**

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:36:38: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'Subclass'
     Subclass * subObj = new Subclass();
                                      ^
Subclass.h:13:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'Subclass':
 class Subclass : SubInterface {
       ^
SuperInterface.h:13:18: note:   virtual void SuperInterface::doSomething()
     virtual void doSomething()=0;
```

**Here are my sources:**

```
#include <iostream>

class SuperInterface {
public:
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
protected:
    int someValue;
};

class SubInterface : public SuperInterface {
public:
    virtual void doSomethingElseThatHasNothingToDoWithTheOtherMethod() = 0;
protected:
    int anotherValue;
};

class Superclass : public SuperInterface {
public:
    Superclass() {}
    virtual ~Superclass() {}
    void doSomething() {std::cout << "hello stackoverflow!";}
};

class Subclass : public SubInterface {
public:
    Subclass() {}
    virtual ~Subclass() {}
    void doSomethingElseThatHasNothingToDoWithTheOtherMethod() {std::cout << "goodbye stackoverflow!";}

};

int main(void)
{
    Superclass * superObj = new Superclass();
    Subclass * subObj = new Subclass();
}
```

**Here's what I want:**
I want my implementation to be aware and so have the same behaviour as of already overriden methods (e.g `subObj->doSomething()` method works without the need to implement it again). Can anyone tell me what I should do to make that happen if it's even possible? Thanks.

Comment: Just parsing your code with my eyes. Seens like Subclass is declaring doSomethingElse as pure virtual. That's a typo, correct?

Comment: Derive publicly, get rid of the =0 in Subclass::doSomethingElse declaration and implement doSomething in Subclass. Well you don't have to derive publicly but it's probably what you want.. Classes inherit privately by default. I use structs for pure interfaces.

Comment: That's a typo, my bad and I renamed the other method to make it clear that both methods have different behaviour.

Comment: @codah when you say implement doSomething in Subclass you are asking me to do exactly what I don't want to do. I am looking for an alternative that makes the need of any further implementation of a method unnecessary. And I don't want to implement it in SubInterface either since I want to keep interface and Implementation separated and inheritence in Implementation always present

Comment: ok sorry, I misunderstood; retracted.

Comment: @PaikuHan: This question makes little sense, did you intend for `Subclass` to derive from `SuperClass`?  As it is, `Subclass` has never had the function implemented...

Comment: Also, it's common for interfaces to have virtual destructors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do what you want through simple inheritance. At no point does Subclass inherit, or provide, an implementation of `doSomething()`, so you can't call `subObj->doSomething()` as you desire. You must honour the interface contract of `subInterface`.

You could inherit `Subclass` from `Superclass` and `Subinterface`, and just implement `doSomething()` as  a kind of proxy, `Superclass::doSomething()`. You still need an implementation but you don't have to 're-implement' it.

Answer (score 3):

You're getting the error because you're trying to create an object of an abstract class.
Your `Subclass` is an abstract class because of this line `void doSomethingElse()=0;`.
If a class has one pure virtual function, it will be an abstract class. You can't create an object of an abstract class, you can only have a reference or a pointer to it.

To get rid of the error, the declaration of `doSomethingElse` in `Subclass` should be

```
void doSomethingElse();
```

Instead of `void doSomethingElse()=0;`

Also I don't see why you need two interfaces. You could derive `Subclass` from the `SuperInterface`, as it is basically just the same as `SubInterface`

Comment: doSomethingElse() renamed to make it clear that doSomething() and doSomethingElse() have absolutely nothing in commons I may as well have a completely different behaviour and return type. the =0 was a typo now corrected!

Answer (score 0):

Your class 'Subclass' should override 2 pure virtual methods, so:

```
class Subclass : SubInterface {
public:
    Subclass();
    virtual ~Subclass();
    void doSomethingElse() override;
    void doSomething() override;
};
```

by not doing so or stating

> void doSomethingElse()=0;

class Subclass becomes abstract too, which cannot be instantiated. You could havea look at :http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pure-virtual-fns.html

> Here's what I want: I want my implementation to be aware and so have
>   the same behaviour as of already overriden methods (e.g
>   subObj->doSomething() method works without the need to implement it
>   again). Can anyone tell me what I should do to make that happen if
>   it's even possible!!?? Thanks.

--> maybe declare the methods virtual not pure virtual

Comment: Could add 'override' to the method declarations.

Comment: I know why the subclass became abstract as well, my question is: is there a way, a workaround not to have to override again an already overriden method.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I am not *entirely* sure what your design wants to express, but there are at least two technical errors here:

1.) You use **private** inheritance in all cases, so you do not actually deal with "interfaces" at all. Public inheritance is achieved like this:

```
class SubInterface : public SuperInterface
```

2.) You use `=0` for a function you apparently want to implement.

This will fix the compiler errors, but the design is still questionable. Considering the motivation you gave at the end of your question, I recommend composition rather than (public) inheritance. In C++, to share functionality is best expressed with composition. To put it very brief, encapsulate the commonly used functionality in a separate class and equip the other classes with an object of it.

```
class CommonFunctionality
{
//...
public:
    void doSomething();
    void doSomethingElse();
};

class SuperClass
{
//...
private:
    CommonFunctionality m_functionality;
};

class SubClass : public SuperClass
{
//...
private:
    CommonFunctionality m_functionality;
};
```

In fact, perhaps you don't even *need* to create a class for CommonFunctionality. Perhaps simple **free-standing functions** would do. Programmers with a Java background (and your code looks a bit like it) tend to put too stuff into classes than what is necessary in C++.

Comment: That's a typo, my bad and I renamed the other method to make it clear that both methods have different behaviour. By the way adding "public" to the inheritance statement doesn't change a thing on the errors

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems, which are clearly stated by compiler:

**Problem 1**

`SubInterface::doSomethingElse()()` in `Subclass` is declared as pure virtual, disregarding that you trying to define it in source file (I'm pretty sure, that this is a copy-paste kind of errors).

```
class Subclass : SubInterface
{
public:
    Subclass();
    virtual ~Subclass();
    void doSomethingElse() = 0; // still pure? 
};
```

Solution is obvious:

```
class Subclass : SubInterface
{
public:
    Subclass();
    virtual ~Subclass();
    virtual void doSomethingElse() override 
    {   
    }

};
```

(here using C++11 `override` specifier, so compiler will check correctness of overriding; it is not obligatory)

**Problem 2**

`doSomething()` is not even tried to be overriden, neither in `SuperInterface`, nor in `Subclass`, so it stays pure virtual. Although `doSomething()` is overriden in `Superclass`, `Subclass` has no idea about existance of `Superclass`.

[image]

Solution: override `doSomething()` either in `SuperInterface`, or in `Subclass`, or in any of children of `Subclass` (don't have them yet). For example, overriding in `Subclass`:

```
class Subclass : SubInterface
{
public:
    Subclass();
    virtual ~Subclass();
    virtual void doSomething() override 
    {   
    }

    virtual void doSomethingElse() override 
    {   
    }

};
```

**Other issues:**

- You are inheriting without visibility specifier, i.e. `privat`ely. Use `public` inheritance until you really need something else:

  ```
  class Derved : public Base {};
  ```
- Your source files have `.c` extension, but containing C++ code. This can confuse some compilers if you do not state programming language explicitly via command line arguments. By convention, most programmers use `.cpp` extension, and most compilers treat such files as C++ source files.

Comment: correction of my code. The truth is I had deleted part of my code inadvertently. I also made some modification to make the whole thing I hope clearer!

Comment: @PaikuHan BTW, it is not recommended that you edit your first post fixing problems. This adds confusion to anyone who will read this thread later.

Comment: the .c extension is a typo as you might have noticed reading the error code which gives the filenames with cpp extension. The override specifier isn't recognized by my IDE and on compiling I get errors stating that, as you said, it will only work with c++11. But my biggest problem with your solution is that even though you've overriden your doSomething() in  Superclass you will still have to override it again either in the SubInterface or in Subclass. Now I guess the real question is: Is there really no other way to do it ... multiple inheritance for the Subclass maybe???

Comment: I understand there certainly would be confusion but the only other solution would be to delete the whole post and write it all over again